# Hijacked gmail. No longer able to access

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I need to take back control of my gmail. And figure out how to protect myself.

Comment: sorry for your trouble, but this question desnt fit to Stack Overflow. Try SuperUser sub-site

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [support page: **Recover a hijacked or stolen Google Account**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6294825?hl=en). If there's unusual activity on your account, you've gotten an email from Google about suspicious activity, or you can no longer get into your account, it might have been compromised.

Please check the **signs that your account has been compromised**.

***What you should do to recover a hijacked account?***

*If you can still sign in to your account...*

- Secure your account
- Sign in to your account again
- Remove a possible virus

*If you can no longer sign in to your account...*

- If you can't sign in to your account, [follow the steps to recover your account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).

*If you notice a red bar at the top of your account...*

- We highly recommend you click the link in the bar that allows you to see a list of the devices you recently used to detect anything suspicious.

Hope this helps!